# Optimize query using include in rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, query-optimization

I need to optimize this query because it's taking more time and I
want to approve group with `group_category` and `user_comments`.

```
@latest = Group.scope_approved
               .order('id desc')
               .includes(:group_category, :user_comments)
               .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

There is thousands of records in group.

I am using 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'

Any idea?

(from Comment)

```
Group Load (5.4ms) 
SELECT  groups.*
    FROM  groups
    WHERE  groups.approved = 1
    ORDER BY  id desc
    LIMIT  10 OFFSET 0

GroupCategory Load (1.2ms) 
SELECT  group_categories.*
    FROM  group_categories
    WHERE  group_categories.id IN (16, 3, 10, 1, 14)

UserComment Load (73635.3ms) 
SELECT  user_comments.*
    FROM  user_comments
    WHERE  user_comments.commentable_type = 'Group'
      AND  user_comments.commentable_id IN (67142, 67141, 67140,
                67137, 67136, 67135, 67134, 67131, 67130, 67129)

(61.3ms)
SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM  groups
    WHERE  groups.approved = 1
```

Comment: show your log when the query is getting fire as well as show your scope_approved method

Comment: Group Load (5.4ms)  SELECT  `groups`.* FROM `groups` WHERE `groups`.`approved` = 1  ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
  GroupCategory Load (1.2ms)  SELECT `group_categories`.* FROM `group_categories` WHERE `group_categories`.`id` IN (16, 3, 10, 1, 14)
  UserComment Load (73635.3ms)  SELECT `user_comments`.* FROM `user_comments` WHERE `user_comments`.`commentable_type` = 'Group' AND `user_comments`.`commentable_id` IN (67142, 67141, 67140, 67137, 67136, 67135, 67134, 67131, 67130, 67129)
   (61.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `groups` WHERE `groups`.`approved` = 1

Comment: please clear this code from comment and attach it with your question

Comment: scope_approved is Group scope for display approved group.

Comment: Show the code for `scoped_approved`. What "more time" means? Did you benchmark it? How much time the query is taking compared to the request time?

Comment: @lcguida scope :scope_approved, -> { where(:approved => true) } also please check time in first comments.
its take (73635.3ms) time for load only user_comments

Comment: Have you tried to `EXPLAIN` your resulting query in the database, to see whats happening? Do you have indexes configured to the `User` - `Comments` relation?

Comment: What does `'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'` mean?  That is not a MySQL version number.

Comment: How many rows in each table?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: Where is the pagination done?  Is see nothing in the SQL do help with such.

Comment: @rickJames 
  create_table "user_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "creator_id",   limit: 4,                     null: false
    t.integer  "recipient_id", limit: 4,                     null: false
    t.text     "text",         limit: 65535
    t.boolean  "approved",     limit: 1,     default: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "parent_id",    limit: 4
  end

Comment: create_table "group_categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",        limit: 255
    t.string   "slug",        limit: 255
    t.text     "description", limit: 65535
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

Comment: create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",              limit: 255
    t.string   "slug",              limit: 255
    t.text     "description",       limit: 65535
    t.boolean  "approved",          limit: 1
    t.datetime "moderated_at"
    t.integer  "created_by",        limit: 4
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "group_category_id", limit: 4
  end

Comment: @ChaudharyPrakash - I can't read those `create_tables`; please provide the SQL equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

`user_comments` would benefit from `INDEX(commentable_type, commentable_id)` (in that order).  This would speed up the 3rd query.